# What's the best way to check uniform data?

Tags: c++, c++11, software-design

I need an idea for the following situation (see code for clarity): Having several instances of struct `MyData`, what is the most concise way to check the instances for uniformity and returning a uniform instance. How can I reduce code duplication while maintaining readability?
Uniformity means having the same values.

Given this example:

```cpp
struct MyData {
   int foo;
   int bar;
   // ...
}

void print(MyData d)
{
    std::cout << "MyData[" << d.foo << ", " << d.bar << "]" std::endl;
}

MyData data1 = {5, 6};
MyData data2 = {5, 6};
MyData data3 = {5, 42};
```

I'm looking for a good code style to get the desired output:

```cpp
isUniform(data1, data2);
 >>> MyData[5, 6]

isUniform(data1, data2, data3);
 >>> "Not uniform"
```

Comment: By uniformity, I think you are referring to equality here? Define a member function in the struct which wraps the equality operator.

Answer (score 1):

First, define an equality operator for `MyData` so we can compare instances:

```
bool operator == (MyData const &lhs, MyData const &rhs) {
    return std::tie(lhs.foo, lhs.bar)
        == std::tie(rhs.foo, rhs.bar);
}
```

Note: this will soon get easier in C++20 with `operator <=>`.

Then, it's just a matter of unpacking all of the arguments to `isUniform` and see if they are all equal. C++11 solution here, C++17 below.

```
template <class First, class... Rest>
bool isUniform(First const &first, Rest const &... rest) {
    bool all_equal = true;

    bool expander[]{ false, (all_equal = all_equal && first == rest)... };
    static_cast<void>(expander);

    return all_equal;
}
```

Usage looks like:

```
if(isUniform(data1, data2))
    print(data1);
else
    std::cout << "Not uniform\n";
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dVE1NYUxG5AYzClx)

---

C++17 version:

```
template <class First, class... Rest>
std::optional<First> isUniform(First const &first, Rest const &... rest) {
    if(((first == rest) && ...))
        return first;

    return {};
}
```

Usage looks like:

```
if(auto o = isUniform(data1, data2, data3))
    print(*o);
else
    std::cout << "Not uniform\n";
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OLyuMOqMFYmcGkiV)

Comment: Dereferencing a potentially empty `optional`?

Comment: @Mansoor if it is empty, its contextual conversion to `bool` will yield `false` and the `else` branch will be taken. No dereferencing there.

Comment: Since I'm on a C++11 compiler, I cannot use this packing `...` syntax. So I would have to write the loop my own, I guess?

Comment: @Quentin Ahh yes, I missed that.

Comment: @Sparkofska please remember to add the relevant tag when using an older version of C++, I've done it for you up there. C++11 requires a lot more boilerplate, but is still feasible.